# Craft POSTGRESQL Query for Times when Items are Within Range of a Sensor

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to figure out the best way to query a time range for when a ship is within a certain range of a sensor. Essentially, I have a database (AIS) of individual ships and their positions at certain points in time

```
Table: AIS    
Columns: ship_id, time, latitude, longitude, range_from_sensor
```

Each row is an individual ship position at a point in time. I would like to query this database for a particular time range and determine the unique ship ID's that are within 20km of the sensor. So for example, if I have a time range of 30 seconds (t1 and t2), I can't just query ship positions between t1 and t2, because the broadcasted ship positions are intermittent and it isn't guaranteed that the ship broadcasted its position within that time range.

So, the solution I have come up with in the meantime is as follows. I want to determine which ships are likely within 20km of the sensor for t1-t2 (30 seconds). I define a new time range, subtracting 24 hours from t1, t1_minus. So my assumption is that any ships that entered the range of 20km of the sensor within the last 24 hours and have not exited after they entered are still within range. So using t1_minus and t2, I do the following query:

```
'SELECT ship_id, MAX("time") FROM AIS WHERE "time" BETWEEN ' + str(t1_minus) + ' AND ' + str(t2) \
+ ' AND range_from_sensor<=20 GROUP BY ship_id'
```

This returns the latest time that each individual ship was inside the sensor range. Then, using this latest time value for each ship, I do another query to see if they exited again before t1, the start of the time range I am interested in. I do the following query for each individual ship to check this, discarding the ships where a value is returned, indicating the ship exited before the time range starts (t1)

```
'SELECT * FROM AIS WHERE time BETWEEN ' + str(max_time) + ' AND ' + str(t1) + \
        ' AND range_from_sensor>20 AND ship_id=' + str(ship_id)
```

Is there another approach to do this that is better? For example, could I first do a query for each ship, make a new database table that just holds the time they entered the range and then exited, then use this to check which ships were in range at a particular moment in time? If so, what would be the best way to execute this? I would know how to use this table once it is created, but what is the best way to create this table using a method like the above?

```
Table: Ship Times
Columns: ship_id, enter_time, exit_time
```

This is part of an application I am building in Python (Flask) using SQLAlchemy and Postgresql

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: You only have one sensor?

Comment: Yes I only have one sensor.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the measurements as PostGIS `POINT M`, where the M coordinate is the time at which the measurement was taken.

Construct a linestring with measure from the points, then use [`ST_LocateBetween`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.1/ST_LocateBetween.html) to extract the probable path of the ship in the desired time interval. Then find all ships where that path is close enough to the sensor.